# No exact matches in call to instance method 'subscribe', Combine Freamwork

Tags: swift, combine

When I want to assign a subscriber to a publisher I get this error:

> No exact matches in call to instance method 'subscribe'

I write the code in `ViewdidLoad`:

```
let textPublisher = NotificationCenter.Publisher(center: .default, name: .labelChange).map({ ($0.object as! String) })
let textsubscriber = Subscribers.Assign(object: textLabel, keyPath: \.text)
textPublisher.subscribe(textsubscriber)
```

Answer (score 1):

Cast `$0.object` as optional.

```
.map({ ($0.object as? String)})
```

For `.subscribe` required the same type as `.Publisher`. But in your case publisher return string and subscriber return optional string so use optional in publisher to fix this issue.

[image]
[image]